# Spring Security JWT Authorization returning 401 on endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, authorization

I am able to register a user then login with those credentials and receive a valid JWT token with userId, username and the roles of a user.

Here is a screenshot of a token with 2 roles (USER and ADMIN)
[jwt.io result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxFx8.png)

I inserted 2 roles (USER and ADMIN) into my roles table manually so that each user created will automatically be assigned a ROLE_USER once created.

The problem is, now that I want to access URLs based on the roles a user has, I am getting 401 unauthorized on endpoints that I tried to grant access to.

This is a postman response from a User who has a role of User and Admin, but I'm getting this 401 still.

[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPq35.png)

Here are the important classes
**My Role entity has a name and description fields**
**My Repository interfaces have a findByXXX method**

---

User.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements UserDetails{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    private boolean enabled = true;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date createdAt;

    // I want to load all the roles of users + the user itself once requested for
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    
    // Constructor
    // Getters and setteres


    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }



}
```

---

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    };

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/register", "/api/users/login", "/api/users/all").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/users/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // handles the json exception response if details are incorrect with an appropriate message
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

---

UserService.java

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;


    public User saveUser(User user) {

        Role userRole = roleService.findByRoleName("USER");
//        Role adminRole = roleService.findByRoleName("ADMIN");
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            user.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            user.setConfirmPassword("");
            roles.add(userRole);
            user.setRoles(roles);

            return userRepository.save(user);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new UsernameAlreadyExistsException("User with username " + user.getUsername() + " already exists!");
        }
    }


    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);
        return list;
    }

}
```

---

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return user;
    }
    
    private Set getAuthority(User user) {
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()));
        });
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

---

JwtTokenProvider.java

```java
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private final String SECRET = "SECRET";
    // Generate the token
    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + 300_000);

        String userId = Long.toString(user.getId());

        // this is what holds the token
        // add roles in claims
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("id", (Long.toString(user.getId())));
        claims.put("username", user.getUsername());
        claims.put("roles", user.getRoles());

        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(userId).setClaims(claims).setIssuedAt(now).setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET).compact();
    }

    // Validate the token
    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT Signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT Token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            System.out.println("Expired JWT Token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println("JWT claims string is empty");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getUsernameFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();
    }
}
```

---

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java

```java
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String jwt = getJWTFromRequest(httpServletRequest);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUsernameFromJWT(jwt);
                User userDetails = (User) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, Collections.emptyList());

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

    }

    private String getJWTFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Header Authorization: Bearer token
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

UserController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@CrossOrigin
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private UserValidator userValidator;
    private ErrorValidationService errorValidationService;
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, UserValidator userValidator, ErrorValidationService errorValidationService, JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.userValidator = userValidator;
        this.errorValidationService = errorValidationService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    // I want to allow role based access to these URLs
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String welcomeAll() {
        return "Anyone can view this!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminPing(){
        return "Only Admins Can view This";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String userPing(){
        return "Any User Can view This";
    }


    // Get all users
    @GetMapping("/userList")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers() {
          return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findAll());
    }

    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) {

        userValidator.validate(user, result);
        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = errorValidationService.validationService(result);
        if(errorMap != null) return errorMap;

        User newUser = userService.saveUser(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<User>(newUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, BindingResult result) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Entering /login");
        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = errorValidationService.validationService(result);
        if(errorMap != null) return errorMap;

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = "Bearer " + tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtLoginSuccessResponse(true, jwt));
    }

}
```

---

If anyone can let me know why this is happening , and how I can go about changing and abstracting things in a much better way I would appreciate it a lot. Since there's so many different implementations online I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging in Spring Security and see which filter blocks the request. This will give you a hint. You might have to debug into the relevant method in the filter to see what's going wrong. It will also help investigate the problem if you can cover this scenario by an automated test. Will make it a lot easier to reproduce and debug

Answer (score 0):

Using `hasAnyAuthority` instead of `hasRole` and remove `"ROLE_"` from `SimpleGrantedAuthority`

- Your code

```java
.antMatchers("/api/users/user/**").hasRole("USER")
//...and...
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()));
```

- Try this

```java
.antMatchers("/api/users/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
//...and...
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
```

- But I dont't see where you use method `UserDetailsServiceImpl.getAuthority`? You put an empty list of `authorities` into `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in `JwtAuthenticationFilter`

```java
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, Collections.emptyList());
```

You should put `authorities` in.

Comment: I have got it now thanks. Spring is really confusing especially for a new comer like my